# Unable to start Elasticsearch after fresh install

Tags: elasticsearch

I have been trying to install elasticsearch without success. Every single guide regardless of if I used the .deb or install from apt fails in the same way. I am using ubuntu 20.04 as an LXC on proxmox. After installing the service start fails and here is the log file

```
[2022-06-10T12:06:13.884+0000][22320][gc,init] CardTable entry size: 512
[2022-06-10T12:06:13.885+0000][22320][gc     ] Using G1
[2022-06-10T12:06:13.957+0000][22320][gc,init] Version: 18.0.1.1+2-6 (release)
[2022-06-10T12:06:13.957+0000][22320][gc,init] CPUs: 24 total, 4 available
[2022-06-10T12:06:13.957+0000][22320][gc,init] Memory: 96593M
[2022-06-10T12:06:13.957+0000][22320][gc,init] Large Page Support: Disabled
[2022-06-10T12:06:13.957+0000][22320][gc,init] NUMA Support: Disabled
[2022-06-10T12:06:13.958+0000][22320][gc,init] Compressed Oops: Enabled (Non-zero disjoint base)
[2022-06-10T12:06:13.958+0000][22320][gc,init] Heap Region Size: 16M
[2022-06-10T12:06:13.958+0000][22320][gc,init] Heap Min Capacity: 31G
[2022-06-10T12:06:13.958+0000][22320][gc,init] Heap Initial Capacity: 31G
[2022-06-10T12:06:13.958+0000][22320][gc,init] Heap Max Capacity: 31G
[2022-06-10T12:06:13.958+0000][22320][gc,init] Pre-touch: Disabled
[2022-06-10T12:06:13.958+0000][22320][gc,init] Parallel Workers: 4
[2022-06-10T12:06:13.958+0000][22320][gc,init] Concurrent Workers: 1
[2022-06-10T12:06:13.958+0000][22320][gc,init] Concurrent Refinement Workers: 4
[2022-06-10T12:06:13.958+0000][22320][gc,init] Periodic GC: Disabled
[2022-06-10T12:06:13.958+0000][22320][gc,metaspace] CDS archive(s) not mapped
[2022-06-10T12:06:13.958+0000][22320][gc,metaspace] Compressed class space mapped at: 0x0000000080000000-0x00000000c0000000, reserved size: 1073741>
[2022-06-10T12:06:13.958+0000][22320][gc,metaspace] Narrow klass base: 0x0000000000000000, Narrow klass shift: 0, Narrow klass range: 0xc0000000
[2022-06-10T12:06:14.152+0000][22320][gc,heap,exit] Heap
[2022-06-10T12:06:14.152+0000][22320][gc,heap,exit]  garbage-first heap   total 32505856K, used 24578K [0x0000001001000000, 0x00000017c1000000)
[2022-06-10T12:06:14.152+0000][22320][gc,heap,exit]   region size 16384K, 2 young (32768K), 0 survivors (0K)
[2022-06-10T12:06:14.152+0000][22320][gc,heap,exit]  Metaspace       used 3525K, committed 3584K, reserved 1114112K
[2022-06-10T12:06:14.152+0000][22320][gc,heap,exit]   class space    used 271K, committed 320K, reserved 1048576K
```

Answer (score 0):

So pretty much all online guides to install elastic search are useless except this one:

https://techviewleo.com/install-elastic-stack-elk-8-on-ubuntu/

For anyone attempting to install elastic search and comes here the main thing this above guide does that the other ones dont is it disables all the security in the yaml file:

Here are the settings that worked for me

```
network.host: localhost
cluster.name: my-application
node.name: node-1

# Enable security features
xpack.security.enabled: false

xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: false

# Enable encryption for HTTP API client connections, such as Kibana, Logstash, and Agents
xpack.security.http.ssl:
  enabled: false
  keystore.path: certs/http.p12

# Enable security features
xpack.security.enabled: false

xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: false

# Enable encryption for HTTP API client connections, such as Kibana, Logstash, and Agents
xpack.security.http.ssl:
  enabled: false
  keystore.path: certs/http.p12
```

As warning this config should not be used for a publicly exposed instance